# PHP passing string with apostrophe to shell_exec

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I’m trying to pass a string (drawn from a PDO query to an MYSQL DB) via PHP `shell_exec` to a *nix program, in this case [xtide](http://www.flaterco.com/xtide/xtide.html).

All works fine until I pass a string containing an apostrophe.

This works in the Terminal on OSX:

```
house@New-MacBook-Pro:~$ tide -l "Nomans Land, Martha's Vineyard, Massachusetts"
```

but the exact same string, from a PDO query to a MYSQL DB, and passed as a variable into shell_exec, always fails. It doesn’t seem to matter how I arrange the single/double quotes.

Running this adds the backslash, but it still fails:

```
$tideLocation = mysql_real_escape_string($tideLocation);
```

outputs:

```
Nomans Land, Martha\’s Vineyard, Massachusetts
```

Failures:

```
$output1 = shell_exec("/opt/local/bin/tide -l 'Nomans Land, Martha's Vineyard, Massachusetts'");

$output1 = shell_exec("/opt/local/bin/tide -l '$tideLocation'");
```

This works, when set up manually in `shell_exec`:

```
$output1 = shell_exec("/opt/local/bin/tide -l 'Nomans Land, Martha\'s Vineyard, Massachusetts'");
```

Advice most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`escapeshellarg`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to properly escape a string in single quotes for a command line arguments.

### Example:

```php
$command = '/opt/local/bin/tide -l ' . escapeshellarg($tideLocation);
shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Brilliant, I had missed escapeshellarg completely. Thanks